# Regex Extracting After the Match

Tags: php, html, regex

```
preg_match('/\$(\d+\.\d+)/',$message,$keywords);
dd($keywords);
```

Hi , have got a  few questions

1) Is it possible to detect/extract the text after the regular expression? eg I'm trying to detect $1.20 possible to detect the text after it eg per hour , /hr , per hr, / hour.

1.1) Maybe like Extract 20 characters after the match

1.2) Possible to know the position of the match if i cant extract?

$100000/hour test test test

Extract test test tst

Comment: What is the input? e.g. value of $message

Comment: Just added the "input" it can be any

Comment: Something like this? https://regex101.com/r/cX2yU8/3

Comment: the solution I am thinking about is not related to regex. assuming there is already a match just take a substring of the message starting index of the match + the length of the keyword until the message length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Put everything you want to extract in the regex, like this:

```
preg_match('#\$(\d+\.\d+)(\s+per hour|\s*/hr|\s+per hr|\s*/hour)?#',$message,$keywords);
```

You'll get the amount in $keywords[1] and the other piece of text in $keywords[2];

1.1) Use `/\$(\d+\.\d+)(.{,20})/` to get at most 20 characters in the second match (if you remove the comma it will match only if after the amount there are at least 20 characters).

1.2) Use the `$flags` parameter of `preg_match()`: `preg_match('/\$(\d+\.\d+)/',$message,$keywords,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);`. Check `print_r($keywords)` to see how the matched values and their offsets are returned

You probably need to find all the appearances. In this case use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: Hi, Can you help me place it into https://regex101.com >.< Trying to learn Regex Thanks! Had issue when doing so >.<

Comment: The `preg_*` PHP functions accept many characters as [regex delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Because you want to match `'/'` I used `#` as regex delimiter to keep the regex simpler (if I use `'/'` as a delimiter then I have to quote it inside the regex). https://regex101.com uses `'/'` by default but if you click on it you can use other character as delimiter. (f.e. `'@'`)

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
$re = '~\$(\d+\.?\d+)/?(\w+)?~m'; 
$str = "$100000/hour\n$100.2000/min"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

**[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eO4oM3/2)**

**Output**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '$100000/hour' (length=12)
      1 => string '$100.2000/min' (length=13)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '100000' (length=6)
      1 => string '100.2000' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'hour' (length=4)
      1 => string 'min' (length=3)
```